# DB2 SQL Union Struggles

Tags: sql, db2, union

Hi this is my first post on Stack Overflow. I've read a lot of posts where people were able to have their issues solved so here goes. I am having a hard time getting the following union to work. I am not sure what is wrong and the error message from SQL Developer is not helpful. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

The error message I am getting is:

> "Error report -
>
> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC="";ECT 'IN' AS STATE
>     ,;, DRIVER=4.7.112"

This is the DDL I am trying to get to work:

```
CREATE VIEW DW_COE.DAMAGE_FINANCIALS ("STATE"
,"CLAIM_NUMBER"
,"DAMAGE_DATE"
,"LABOR_FEE"
,"EQUIPMENT_FEE"
,"MATERIALS_FEE"
,"MEALS_FEE"
,"CONTRACTED_FEE"
,"POLICE_REPORTS_FEE"
,"GAS_LOSS_FEE"
,"TAXES_FEE"
,"GENERAL_FEE"
,"JO_NO") AS

SELECT DPTS.STATE AS STATE
,Dpts.claim_number AS CLAIM_NUMBER
,DPTS.damagedate AS DAMAGE_DATE
,DPTS.LABOR AS LABOR_FEE
,DPTS.EQUIPMENT AS EQUIPMENT_FEE
,DPTS.MATERIALS AS MATERIALS_FEE
,DPTS.MEALS AS MEALS_FEE
,DPTS.CONTRACTED_FEES AS CONTRACTED_FEE
,DPTS.POLICE_REPORTS AS POLICE_REPORTS_FEE
,DPTS.GAS_LOSS AS GAS_LOSS_FEE
,DPTS.TAXES AS TAXES_FEE
,DPTS.GENERAL AS GENERAL_FEE
,DPTS.JOBORDERNUMBER AS JO_NO
FROM dw_coe.dpts_view DPTS

UNION

SELECT 'IN' AS STATE
,"" AS CLAIM_NUMBER
,"" AS DAMAGE_DATE
,STAR.LABOR AS LABOR_FEE
,STAR.EQUIPMENT AS EQUIPMENT_FEE
,STAR.MATERIAL AS MATERIALS_FEE
,STAR.MEALS AS MEALS_FEE
,STAR.CONTRACTEDFEES AS CONTRACTED_FEE
,STAR.POLICEREPORT AS POLICE_REPORTS_FEE
,STAR.GASLOSS AS GAS_LOSS_FEE
,"" AS TAXES_FEE
,"" AS GENERAL_FEE
,STAR.JOB_ORDER_NUM AS JO_NO
FROM dw_coe.star_view STAR 

UNION

SELECT 'IN' AS STATE
,CAST(GFORMS.REPORT_ID AS VARCHAR(50)) AS CLAIM_NUMBER
,GFORMS.ACCIDENT_DATE AS DAMAGE_DATE
,"" AS LABOR_FEE
,"" AS EQUIPMENT_FEE
,"" AS MATERIALS_FEE
,"" AS MEALS_FEE
,"" AS CONTRACTED_FEE
,"" AS POLICE_REPORTS_FEE
,"" AS GAS_LOSS_FEE
,"" AS TAXES_FEE
,"" AS GENERAL_FEE
,GFORMS.JOB_ORDER_NUMBER AS JO_NO
FROM DDH_GFORMS.DAMAGE_DETAIL GFORMS
WITH UR;
```

Comment: Build the query one subquery can column at a time.  That will let you know what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quote " is used for enclose identifiers (f ex column names)

Single quote ' is used for string literals.

Replace your "" with ''

Comment: That was it. Thank you!